# Grouping items in a foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, loops, grouping

So, I'm trying to make a sort of user-market type thing. There's a database with `item_names`, basically describes the virtual items, then there's another table `market`, where when a user lists one of their items, it's put for sale on the user-user market.

My only problem here is I want to group it by item name, referenced in the `item_name` table. I know I could do a bunch of if/else statements but that's extraneous not only because there's a lot of items, but also because I will add more items as time goes on. I want the end result to be something like

```
--[Water for sale]---------------------+

[50 water for sale] [20 water for sale]

[10 water for sale] [10 water for sale]

--[Chips for sale]----------------------+

[50 chips for sale] [20 chips for sale]

[10 chips for sale] [10 chips for sale]
```

And so on, done dynamically.

Any help?

Comment: http://www.garfieldtech.com/blog/php-group-by-with-arrays

Answer (score 6):

Fetch data:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $itemName = $row["item_name"];
  if (!array_key_exists($itemName, $data)) {
    $data[$itemName] = array();
  }
  $data[$itemName][] = $row;
}
```

Display data

```
foreach ($data as $itemName => $rows) {
  echo '<h1>', $itemName, '</h1>';
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo '<li>', $row["article_name"], '</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you *order* (not *group*) the results on your SQL query, then the loop will be very simple (assuming PDO, and a column `item_name` on table `item_names`):

```
$sth = $dbh->query ("SELECT * FROM item_names ORDER BY item_name");
$lastname = '';
while ($row = $sth->fetch()) {
    if($lastname != $row['item_name']) {
        echo '<h1>' . $row['item_name'] . '</h1>';
    }
    // echo contents for each item here

    // remember name from last row
    $lastname = $row['item_name'];
}
```