# Categorize foreach loop results with subheaders

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am displaying the result of a repeater field (wordpress/acf) with the following code :

```
<?php 
$rows = get_field('resa_table');
if( $rows ) { 

echo '<table>';

foreach( $rows as $row ) {
$name = $row['name']; 
$department = $row['department']; 
?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $department; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php } echo '</table>'; } ?>
```

I would like - at least - to sort the results by "department" values. I looked it up on other threads and it doesn't seem too complicated.

I haven't tried it yet though, because what I want to do is a little more complex : I would like to categorize the results by position values AND add a header row before each new "department", in order to get to this result :

```
<table>
<tr class="department"><td>Marketing</td></tr>
<tr><td>John</td></tr>
<tr><td>Mary</td></tr>
<tr class="department"><td>Finance</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jack</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jane</td></tr>
</table>
```

Is this doable ?

Comment: You need to first make sure that the data is sorted how you want, and if you are dealing with ACF, it probably won’t be. But then you just need to keep track of the “last” row’s header, and if it changes, echo it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10710441/231316

Answer (score 1):

I make one array like yours data and try make what you want..
Here php codes;

```
        <?php

    $rows =  array(
        array("name" => "jhon", "department" => "Marketing"),
        array("name" => "mary", "department" => "Marketing"),
        array("name" => "Jack", "department" => "Finance"),
        array("name" => "Jane", "department" => "Finance")
    );    

    // update 
    // these codes will sort the array by department.
    $department = array_column($rows, 'department');
    array_multisort($department, SORT_DESC, $rows);
    // update

    if ($rows) {
        echo '<table>';
        $check_department = "";

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $name = $row['name'];
            $department = $row['department'];

            if ($check_department !=  $department) {
                $check_department  = $row['department'];
                echo "<tr class=\"" . $department . "\"><td>" . $department . "</td></tr>";
            } else {
            }
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php

        }
        echo '</table>';
    } ?>
```

This codes result is;

```
     <table>
     <tr class="Marketing"><td>Marketing</td></tr>                
     <tr><td>jhon</td></tr>
     <tr><td>mary</td></tr>
     <tr class="Finance"><td>Finance</td></tr>                
     <tr><td>Jack</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Jane</td></tr>
     </table>
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Mustafa,
Thank you very much for the detailed code ! I'll try it this weekend and accept it afterwards)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. When I looked at the codes again, I realized a mistake. If this array is not sequential, it will return an incorrect result.
before **foreach**
`$department = array_column($rows, 'department');`
`array_multisort($department, SORT_DESC, $rows);`
You must use the codes. These codes will sort your list. Or you can sort your directory by department as you wish. i updated my answer.

Comment: The problem that I see with this answer is that $rows is an acf repeater field, and this answer is using a static array.